# Finding means and stds of a bunch of torch.Tensors (that are converted from ndarray images)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, mean, numpy-ndarray

```
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
img = to_tensor(train_dataset[0]['image'])
img
```

Converts my images values between 0 and 1 which is expected.  It also converts `img` which is an `ndarray` to a `torch.Tensor`.

Previously, without using `to_tensor` (which I need it now), the following code snippet worked (not sure if this is the best way to find means and stds of the train set, however now doesn't work. How can I make it work?

```
image_arr = []

for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    image_arr.append(to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['image']))

print(np.mean(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
print(np.std(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-0e007c030629> in <module>
      4     image_arr.append(to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['image']))
      5 
----> 6 print(np.mean(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
      7 print(np.std(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))

<__array_function__ internals> in mean(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   3333 
   3334     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 3335                           out=out, **kwargs)
   3336 
   3337 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    133 
    134 def _mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
--> 135     arr = asanyarray(a)
    136 
    137     is_float16_result = False

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    136 
    137     """
--> 138     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    139 
    140 

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: This link might help you: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-the-mean-from-a-list-of-tensors/31989

Comment: Could you actually provide an answer if possible? I am not sure how to use the given hints on my code.

Comment: My hint was to use `stack` and `mean` from `pytorch,` as it provided in the following answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
train_dataset = torch.rand(100, 32, 32, 3)
image_arr = []
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()

for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    # to tensor will give you a tensor which is emulated here by reading the tensor at i
    image_arr.append(train_dataset[i])

print(torch.mean(torch.stack(image_arr, dim=0), dim=(0, 1, 2)))
print(torch.std(torch.stack(image_arr, dim=0), dim=(0, 1, 2)))
```

What did I do?

I used `torch.stack` to concatenate image array into a single torch tensor and use `torch.mean` and `torch.std` to compute stats. I would not recommend converting back to numpy for the purpose of evaluating stats as it can lead to unnecessary conversion from GPU to CPU.

**More information on which dimension is the channel:**
The above example assumes the last dimension is the channel and the image is 32x32x3 with 100 batch size. This is usually the case when the image is loaded using PIL (pillow) or numpy. Images are loaded as HWC (height width channel) in that case. This also seems to be the dimension in the question asked looking at the code example.

If the image tensor is CHW format, then you should use

```
print(torch.mean(torch.stack(image_arr, dim=0), dim=(0, 2, 3)))
print(torch.std(torch.stack(image_arr, dim=0), dim=(0, 2, 3)))
```

Torch tensors are usually CHW format as Conv layers expect CHW format. This is done automatically when the `toTensor` transform is applied to an image (PIL image). For complete rules see documentation of `toTensor` [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor).

Comment: well this is wrong since I am expecting a tensor of size 3 for mean while I am receiving a tensor of size 800 for mean https://imgur.com/a/l1mY9L8

Comment: That would have to do with which dimension is the channel. In the working example it is the 3rd dimension. Since torch uses NCHW by default (please make sure this is the case), you might have to change `dim=(0, 1, 2)` to `dim=(0, 2, 3)`

Comment: I'm not sure how. could you please help with that?

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if that does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please potentially add a little explanation to answer about these 0, 1, 2, 3 and how one had 0, 1, 2 and the other 0, 2, 3 and how I should know when to use each? Very helpful.

Comment: I have tried to elaborate more on CHW vs HWC. (0,1,2) Vs (0,2,3) is just really low-level detail and depends on across which dimensions you want the stats. Since you want stats for each channel you exclude that dimension and average across all other dimensions.  

As an example, if you wanted the average image, you would average across batch dimension and say `dim=0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223072/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-umang-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compute the mean of tensor using numpy?

You need to convert your data to NumPy then compute `mean` and `std` as

```
image_arr = []
for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
       image_arr.append((to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['image'])).cpu().detach().numpy())

print(np.mean(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
print(np.std(image_arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
```

Comment: this is also wrong since I am expecting a tensor of size 3 for mean but I am getting a tensor of size 800! https://imgur.com/a/eJ0eQsm I am expecting to get the mean for each RGB channel so only three values!

Comment: Print the shape of the image_arr and then in add/remove axis in axis=(0, 1, 2).